# Mongodb connection from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, docker, laravel-8

I tried to use MongoDB cache for Laravel : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

I have a Docker container for MongoDB and I set all variables :

```
MONGO_DB_HOST=mongodb
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=cache
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=root
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=111
```

and I set :

```
CACHE_DRIVER=mongodb
```

When I tried to connect to this MongoDB container :

`# docker exec -it backend curl http://mongodb:27017

It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.`

And when I did `docker logs -f mongodb` I have : `{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-10T08:28:15.554+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641803295:554092][1:0x7f669bbde700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 9859, snapshot max: 9859 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 1345"}}`

And in Laravel logs I have: `production.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded {"userId":63,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded at /box/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/CarbonTimeZone.php:88)` seems that is related to mongodb connection.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb use the protocol `mongodb://`.
Your connection test should be `# docker exec -it backend curl mongodb://mongodb:27017`